# Market Making why using the exponential utility function

Tags: market-making

In High-frequency trading in a limit order book by MARCO AVELLANEDA and SASHA STOIKOV they say that the MM wants to maximize the following function:

$$v(x, s, q, t) =  E[-exp(- \gamma(x+qS_T)] $$

Is there any justification why a MM will want to maximimze this function? Why taking the exponential, why not directly maximizing the PnL.

Intuitively I would say that the MM wants to maximize:

$$ \Sigma_i \text{Margin_PnL}_i  + \Sigma_j S_t-b_j + \Sigma_k a_k-S_T$$

where the Margin_PnL_i are all the situations where the MM was able to buy and sell the asset or sell and buy the asset. And the b_j are the price at which the MM bought the asset and are still in the inventory and the a_k or the short position still in the inventory.

So what's the problem with my reasoning, and how does it relate to the optmization problem above?